# Double to fraction in Java

Tags: java, double, fractions

So what I'm trying to do is convert double to rational number. I check how many digits there is after decimal point and I want to save the number 123.456 as 123456 / 1000, for example.

```
public Rational(double d){      
    String s = String.valueOf(d);
    int digitsDec = s.length() - 1 - s.indexOf('.');        

    for(int i = 0; i < digitsDec; i++){
        d *= 10;
    }

    System.out.println((int)d); //checking purposes
}
```

However, for the number 123.456 I get a round off error and the result is 123455. I guess it'd be possible to fix this with BigDecimal but I can't get it to work. Also, having calculated what rational number it would be, I would like to call another constructor with parameters (int numerator, int denominator) but I can't obviously call the constructor in the line where println is now. How should I do this?

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to just count the location of the dot and then remove (string replace) the dot from the string?

Comment: Can't you just put all the decimals from behind the dot in front of it while also counting the amount of numbers you took? Remove the dot, parse everything back to int and create a 2nd int using 10 times the amount of numbers you took?

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but o you know that any rational number has an infinite number of fractional representations? One option would be searching for the **canonical fraction**, but that is slightly more complicated of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also off topic, but you may want to consider some rounding algorithm. For instance, a double can't represent 1/10 exactly, but I'm not sure if you'd want to represent the rational number 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. Alternatively, as you mention, you could just use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first part of the question, Java is storing .6 as .5999999 (repeating). See this output:

```
(after first multiply): d=1234.56
(after second multiply): d=12345.599999999999
(after third multiply): d=123455.99999999999
```

One fix is to use d = Math.round(d) immediately after your loop finishes.

```
public class Rational {

     private int num, denom;

     public Rational(double d) {
          String s = String.valueOf(d);
          int digitsDec = s.length() - 1 - s.indexOf('.');        

          int denom = 1;
          for(int i = 0; i < digitsDec; i++){
             d *= 10;
             denom *= 10;
          }
          int num = (int) Math.round(d);

          this.num = num; this.denom = denom;
     }

     public Rational(int num, int denom) {
          this.num = num; this.denom = denom;
     }

     public String toString() {
          return String.valueOf(num) + "/" + String.valueOf(denom);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println(new Rational(123.456));
     }
}
```

It works - try it.

For the second part of your question...

In order to call the second constructor from the first, you can use the "this" keyword

```
this(num, denom)
```

But it has to be the very first line in the constructor... which doesn't make sense here (we have to do some calculations first). So I wouldn't bother trying to do that.

Comment: Multiplying by 10.0 didn't change the result.

Comment: Regarding the second part: probably I didn't state my problem precisely enough. I've got two constructors: first with the parameter (double d), another with (int num, int denom). In the first one I want to convert double number to fraction and call the second constructor.

Comment: Java is storing your double 123.456 as 123455.999999 after you finish multiplying by 10. One way to get the proper value is to round here.

Comment: See my revised post - I tested it and got 123456/1000 as my standard output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's fine now.

Answer (score 5):

This code may be overkill for you, but it deals with the rounding error that you're experiencing, and it also takes care of repeating decimals (4.99999999999999 turns into 5, and 0.33333333333333333333 turns into 1/3).

```
public static Rational toRational(double number){
return toRational(number, 8);
}

public static Rational toRational(double number, int largestRightOfDecimal){

long sign = 1;
if(number < 0){
    number = -number;
    sign = -1;
}

final long SECOND_MULTIPLIER_MAX = (long)Math.pow(10, largestRightOfDecimal - 1);
final long FIRST_MULTIPLIER_MAX = SECOND_MULTIPLIER_MAX * 10L;
final double ERROR = Math.pow(10, -largestRightOfDecimal - 1);
long firstMultiplier = 1;
long secondMultiplier = 1;
boolean notIntOrIrrational = false;
long truncatedNumber = (long)number;
Rational rationalNumber = new Rational((long)(sign * number * FIRST_MULTIPLIER_MAX), FIRST_MULTIPLIER_MAX);

double error = number - truncatedNumber;
while( (error >= ERROR) && (firstMultiplier <= FIRST_MULTIPLIER_MAX)){
    secondMultiplier = 1;
    firstMultiplier *= 10;
    while( (secondMultiplier <= SECOND_MULTIPLIER_MAX) && (secondMultiplier < firstMultiplier) ){
        double difference = (number * firstMultiplier) - (number * secondMultiplier);
        truncatedNumber = (long)difference;
        error = difference - truncatedNumber;
        if(error < ERROR){
            notIntOrIrrational = true;
            break;
        }
        secondMultiplier *= 10;
    }
}

if(notIntOrIrrational){
    rationalNumber = new Rational(sign * truncatedNumber, firstMultiplier - secondMultiplier);
}
return rationalNumber;
}
```

This provides the following results (results from test cases are shown as comments):

```
Rational.toRational(110.0/3.0); // 110/3
Rational.toRational(11.0/1000.0); // 11/1000
Rational.toRational(17357.0/33300.0); // 17357/33300
Rational.toRational(215.0/21.0); // 215/21
Rational.toRational(0.123123123123123123123123); // 41/333
Rational.toRational(145731.0/27100.0); // 145731/27100
Rational.toRational(Math.PI); // 62831853/20000000
Rational.toRational(62.0/63.0); // 62/63
Rational.toRational(24.0/25.0); // 24/25
Rational.toRational(-24.0/25.0); //-24/25
Rational.toRational(-0.25333333333333333333333); // -19/75
Rational.toRational(-4.9999999999999999999999); // -5
Rational.toRational(4.9999999999999999999999);  // 5
Rational.toRational(123.456); // 15432/125
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not elegant, however, I believe this does what you're asking.

```
double a = 123.456;
String aString = Double.toString(a);        
String[] fraction = aString.split("\\.");

int denominator = (int)Math.pow(10, fraction[1].length());
int numerator = Integer.parseInt(fraction[0] + "" + fraction[1]);

System.out.println(numerator + "/" + denominator);
```

Comment: Now simplify :D

Answer (score 3):

Here, d=123.456 then num=123456, j=1000.

```
/**
 * This method calculates a rational number from a double.
 * The denominator will always be a multiple of 10. 
 *
 * @param d the double to calculate the fraction from.
 * @return the result as Pair of <numerator , denominator>.
 */
private static Pair<Integer,Integer> calculateRational(double d){
    int j=1, num;
    do{
        j=j*10;
    }while((d *j)%10!=0);
    j=j/10;
    num=(int)(d*j);
    return new Pair<>(num,j);
}
```

Here're some tests:

```
@Test
public  void testCalculateRational() {
    Assert.assertEquals(new Pair<>(124567, 1000), calculateRational(124.567));
    Assert.assertEquals(new Pair<>(12456, 100), calculateRational(124.56));
    Assert.assertEquals(new Pair<>(56, 100), calculateRational(0.56));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for(int i = 0; i <= digitsDec; i++){

}
```

Comment: I want to convert from number 123.456 to 123456. When I change to i <= digitsDec I get a number 1234559.