# Is there anyway to compute a negative base to the power of a non integer exponent in Java?

Tags: java, math, exponent

According to my own experience and to the Java documentation, in Math.pow(i,j), whenever i is a negative number and j is a non integer, Math.pow will always return NaN, however, according to all of the different calculators I have tried, there are some situations where there is a real solution to a negative base to the power a non integer exponent.

For example:

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(-3, 0.6));
```

returns NaN

Are there any work arounds to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What research have you done? Asking because if there is a good workaround, I would expect it to be described somewhere on the Internet.

Comment: Also, what result would you expect? (I have a clue, but I think you’d better make it explicit yourself.)

Comment: If I am guessing your intention correctly, a first step could be to convert 0.6 to a fraction, here 3 / 5. How to do that? See [Double to fraction in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014158/double-to-fraction-in-java).

Comment: You will have to work with complex numbers, check the stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997053/does-java-have-a-class-for-complex-numbers

Comment: You need complex numbers for that.  There are plenty of complex number implementations out there, I'm sure.  It won't be part of JDK.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/complex.html

Comment: @duffymo x^y with x<0 and 0<y<1 may have real roots (it does in the op's example). See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers

Comment: I think complex numbers would still be the most general solution.  A few isolated cases don't change that.  If there are real roots, the complex solutions will have zero imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you define that power? The standard method is to find the polar decomposition resp. complex logarithm of the base and plug the power into that,

```
pow(-3, 0.6) = exp( 0.6 * (log(3) + i*pi) )
= pow(3,0.6) * (cos(0.6*pi) + i*sin(0.6*pi))
```

Now you could also chose other branches of the logarithm to represent `Ln(-3)`, as it is also true that `-1=exp(-i*pi)=exp(i*3*pi)=exp(-5*i*pi)=exp(i*7*pi)=…`. Only one among those variants will give a real result to the power. However, how is the computer to know that you want exactly that variant? And what do you do for `pow(-3,0.61)`?

Answer (score -1):

According to my own experience and to the Java documentation, in `Math.pow(i,j)`, whenever `i` is a negative number and `j` is a non integer, Math.pow will always return `NaN`, however, according to all of the different calculators I have tried, there are some situations where there is a real solution to a negative base to the power a non integer exponent.

For example:

`System.out.println(Math.pow(-3, 0.6));`

returns `NaN`

There are **not** any work arounds to this sorry

Comment: Yes, there are.