# How to convert a String into percentage value upto 2 decimal places

Tags: java, string, decimal, percentage

I have a string whose value will be like '1/3' or '1/2'. It can be even '2/3'. I need to convert it into its equivalent percentage value upto 2 decimal places and again convert it into String.

Is there any java API already present which does it automatically?

Please let me know if you know any optimum solution for this.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool,* ***software library***, *tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* ***Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it***

Comment: The first problem you can achieve easily. To convert back you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014158/double-to-fraction-in-java).

Comment: Will your input strings be only fractions consisting of two numbers separated by a `/`, or did you want to handle arbitrary arithmetic expressions?  The first is much simpler to do than the second.

Answer (score 1):

below code might resolve this:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class percentage {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String x="2/3";
        System.out.println(convert(x));

    }
    public static String convert(String x){
        int num=0;
        StringTokenizer s= new StringTokenizer(x, "/");
        while(s.hasMoreElements()){
            num =Integer.parseInt(s.nextToken())/Integer.parseInt(s.nextToken());
        }
        return num+"";
    }
}
```

I have wrote a method of my own to resolve this. `convert()` method would return a String which gives the desirable output.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a double to a percentage String you can use:

```
double number = ...;

NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
String formattedString = numberFormat.format(number);
```

Comment: I am using DecimalFormat to convert to 2 decimal places. I wanted to know if it is possible using java 8 in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own method simply splitting string by "/" and then parsing the strings(of array) numerator and denominator into double.